# react-native, react hook form, react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is my code, I like to put a console log so I know when stuff is rendering.

```
const SignUpStepTwoPrivate = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  console.log(
    " %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Sign Up Step Two rendered! %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
  );
  //TODO the watch(password) is re-rendering every input.
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const { control, handleSubmit, watch, formState } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      ...route.params,
      navigation,
      password: "",
    },
  });
  const pwd = watch("password");

  return ( //...some form view with a password input )
```

the call here:

```
console.log(" %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Sign Up Step Two rendered! %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
```

is firing every time I press a key into the password.

I can find a work around by just passing the ...route.params to the next screen but i'm curious if there is a way to use both watch and default values and prevent the component from re-rendering on key entries

I think I read somewhere that setting defaultValues is a good practice. Does it really matter?

Also I'm passing navigation object to the route parameters because I'm using a button like this:

```
        <Button
          mode="contained"
          textColor="#fafafa"
          onPress={handleSubmit(onContinue)}
        >
          Continue
        </Button>
```

I need the navigation object in the `onContinue` function to navigate to next page. Is there a better way of doing that?